# cURL HTTP requests & appended text files -- Unexpected output

Tags: shell, curl, file-io, httprequest, etl

**How can I loop through cURL HTTP requests & save API responses in single appended text files while sleeping 2 seconds in between each API call?**

Script below outputs 2 .txt files – First one (fandata.txt) has some (not all) the data, seems to be overwritten by the last loop. Second (metadata.txt) outputs a .txt with an error that reads

```
Cannot GET /api/artist/
```

I know this is often done with Python Requests library & not cURL but the API docs are written with cURL. Plus, I want to get my feet wet with shell.

```
refreshtoken=$(REDACTED)
livetoken=${refreshtoken:10:225}
auth_header="Authorization: Bearer $livetoken"
auth_header="${auth_header}"
source="{facebook,instagram,soundcloud,wikipedia,twitter,youtube,bandsintown}"                                                                                                                         
dates="since=2017-10-31&until=2018-10-31"

metadata_url="https://api.chartmetric.io/api/artist/$artistid"
for (( artistid=1; artistid<=3; artistid+=1 )); do
    metadata=$(curl -H "${auth_header}" -o metadata.txt "${metadata_url}")                                              
    sleep 2s
done >metadata.txt
echo "$metadata"

fanmetrics_url="https://api.chartmetric.io/api/artist/$artistid/stat/$source?$dates"
for (( artistid=1; artistid<=3; artistid+=1 )); do
    fandata=$(curl -H "${auth_header}" -o fandata.txt "$fanmetrics_url") 
    sleep 2s
done >fandata.txt
echo "$fandata"
```